# What's causing my reboot to an ungraceful shutdown?

Tags: rhel, logs, shutdown, reboot

### My question

Where can I find logs of reboot/shutdown in case of ungraceful shutdown ?

### My Case

On my `redhat 7.9 (3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64)` that have been upgraded from `redhat 6`, a simple `sudo reboot` is causing the VM to crash.
I can see below in logs that it's caused by an ungraceful shutdown by the presence of two consecutive SYSTEM_BOOT:

```bash
[root@rsvsiesigmprd02 wasadmin]# ausearch -i -m system_boot,system_shutdown | tail -7
type=SYSTEM_BOOT msg=audit(11/07/2022 06:18:15.281:6) : pid=765 uid=root auid=unset ses=unset subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm=systemd-update-utmp exe=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-update-utmp hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
----
type=SYSTEM_SHUTDOWN msg=audit(15/07/2022 03:12:06.064:5192) : pid=10697 uid=root auid=unset ses=unset subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm=systemd-update-utmp exe=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-update-utmp hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
----
type=SYSTEM_BOOT msg=audit(15/07/2022 08:38:48.151:6) : pid=767 uid=root auid=unset ses=unset subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm=systemd-update-utmp exe=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-update-utmp hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
----
type=SYSTEM_BOOT msg=audit(18/07/2022 06:17:40.034:6) : pid=767 uid=root auid=unset ses=unset subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm=systemd-update-utmp exe=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-update-utmp hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
```

Also I loose access to the VM via SSH and my last resort is to reboot via VMWare with hard shutdown.

I can't find any information in logs for what's causing this.
I checked :

- 1. /var/log/messages
- 2. journalctl

##### in 1. /var/log/messages

```bash
Jul 15 03:01:31 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Started Session 722 of user ansible.
Jul 15 03:01:34 xxxxxxxxxx python: ansible-ansible.legacy.setup Invoked with filter=[] gather_subset=['all'] fact_path=/etc/ansible/facts.d gather_timeout=10
Jul 15 03:01:43 xxxxxxxxxx python: ansible-ansible.legacy.command Invoked with creates=None executable=None _uses_shell=False strip_empty_ends=True _raw_params=/usr/bin/package-cleanup -y --oldkernels --count=2 removes=None argv=None warn=False chdir=None stdin_add_newline=True stdin=None
Jul 15 03:01:53 xxxxxxxxxx python: ansible-ansible.legacy.yum Invoked with lock_timeout=30 update_cache=False conf_file=None exclude=[] allow_downgrade=False disable_gpg_check=False disable_excludes=None use_backend=auto state=latest disablerepo=[] skip_broken=False releasever=None autoremove=False download_dir=None enable_plugin=[] installroot=/ install_weak_deps=True name=['*'] download_only=False bugfix=False list=None install_repoquery=True update_only=False disable_plugin=[] enablerepo=[] security=True validate_certs=True
Jul 15 03:05:03 xxxxxxxxxx systemd-logind: New session 723 of user wasadmin.
Jul 15 03:05:03 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Started Session 723 of user wasadmin.
Jul 15 03:05:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd-logind: Removed session 723.
Jul 15 03:07:54 xxxxxxxxxx python: ansible-ansible.legacy.setup Invoked with filter=[] gather_subset=['all'] fact_path=/etc/ansible/facts.d gather_timeout=10
Jul 15 03:08:04 xxxxxxxxxx python: ansible-ansible.legacy.command Invoked with creates=None executable=None _uses_shell=False strip_empty_ends=True _raw_params=/sbin/shutdown -r +1 removes=None argv=None warn=False chdir=None stdin_add_newline=True stdin=None
Jul 15 03:08:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Started Delayed Shutdown Service.
Jul 15 03:08:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd-shutdownd: Shutting down at Fri 2022-07-15 03:09:04 CEST (reboot)...
Jul 15 03:08:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd-shutdownd: Creating /run/nologin, blocking further logins...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping Session 721 of user root.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking....
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Unmounting /opt/maximo/data...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Removed slice system-selinux\x2dpolicy\x2dmigrate\x2dlocal\x2dchanges.slice.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Unmounting /opt/maximo/sedif...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopped Dump dmesg to /var/log/dmesg.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Unmounting /opt/maximo/agora...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping RPC bind service...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopped target RPC Port Mapper.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping Session c2 of user wasadmin.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopped target rpc_pipefs.target.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping Session 722 of user ansible.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopped target Timers.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Closed LVM2 poll daemon socket.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping Session 2 of user wasadmin.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping LSB: Starts and stops WebSphere Application Server instances...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx umount: umount.nfs: /opt/maximo/data: device is busy
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx journal: IBM Java[2311]: JVMDUMP039I Traitement de l'événement de vidage "user", détails "" à 2022/07/15 03:09:04 - Veuillez patienter.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping LSB: Starts the Spacewalk Daemon...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx journal: IBM Java[2311]: JVMDUMP032I La machine virtuelle Java a demandé un vidage Java en utilisant '/opt/dump/javacore.20220715.030904.2311.0001.txt' en réponse à un événement
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping Command Scheduler...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping Getty on tty1...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx journal: IBM Java[3796]: JVMDUMP039I Traitement de l'événement de vidage "user", détails "" à 2022/07/15 03:09:04 - Veuillez patienter.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx journal: IBM Java[2310]: JVMDUMP039I Traitement de l'événement de vidage "user", détails "" à 2022/07/15 03:09:04 - Veuillez patienter.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx journal: IBM Java[3220]: JVMDUMP039I Traitement de l'événement de vidage "user", détails "" à 2022/07/15 03:09:04 - Veuillez patienter.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx RSVSIESIGMPRD01ManagerNode_was.init: Stopping WebSphere Application Server - dmgr ...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx journal: IBM Java[3796]: JVMDUMP032I La machine virtuelle Java a demandé un vidage Java en utilisant '/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrvUI01/javacore.20220715.030904.3796.0001.txt' en réponse à un événement
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx journal: IBM Java[3220]: JVMDUMP032I La machine virtuelle Java a demandé un vidage Java en utilisant '/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/dmgr/javacore.20220715.030904.3220.0001.txt' en réponse à un événement
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx journal: IBM Java[2310]: JVMDUMP032I La machine virtuelle Java a demandé un vidage Java en utilisant '/opt/dump/javacore.20220715.030904.2310.0001.txt' en réponse à un événement
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping LSB: Starts and stops IHS...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping ACPI Event Daemon...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopped Resets System Activity Logs.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping Zabbix Agent...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping System Logging Service...
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: Linux version 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-vm-39.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 09:04:02 UTC 2022
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: Command line: root=/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_root ro rd.luks=0 rd.lvm.lv=vg_main/lv_swap rd.md=0 rd.locale.LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc vconsole.keymap=fr-latin9 crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=vg_main/lv_root rd.dm=0 rhgb quiet LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: Disabled fast string operations
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009f7ff] usable
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009f800-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000dc000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000bfedffff] usable
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bfee0000-0x00000000bfefefff] ACPI data
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bfeff000-0x00000000bfefffff] ACPI NVS
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000bff00000-0x00000000bfffffff] usable
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f0000000-0x00000000f7ffffff] reserved
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec0ffff] reserved
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffe0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000063fffffff] usable
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: SMBIOS 2.4 present.
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: DMI: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 12/12/2018
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: Hypervisor detected: VMware
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: vmware: TSC freq read from hypervisor : 2893.203 MHz
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: vmware: Host bus clock speed read from hypervisor : 66000000 Hz
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: vmware: using sched offset of 7222055233 ns
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: e820: last_pfn = 0x640000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: PAT configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- UC
Jul 15 08:38:30 xxxxxxxxxx kernel: total RAM covered: 31744M
```

==> As you can see: system is down from 3:00 to 8:00

##### NB: When I do `sudo reboot -f` the reboot is sucessfull.

Thanks.

Comment: After further investigation, the problem was due to umount of disk that failed (because another program is using it) and this leaves the reboot in hanging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log line wrapped for readability:

```
Jul 15 03:08:04 xxxxxxxxxx python: ansible-ansible.legacy.command Invoked with creates=None \
    executable=None _uses_shell=False strip_empty_ends=True _raw_params=/sbin/shutdown -r +1 \
    removes=None argv=None warn=False chdir=None stdin_add_newline=True stdin=None
```

This looks like someone or something is invoking `shutdown -r +1` using Ansible.

The last messages before shutdown would be:

```
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping LSB: Starts and stops IHS...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping ACPI Event Daemon...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopped Resets System Activity Logs.
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping Zabbix Agent...
Jul 15 03:09:04 xxxxxxxxxx systemd: Stopping System Logging Service...
```

... which would imply a controlled shutdown that has already progressed quite far. After the System Logging Service stops, there is obviously not going to be any further log entries in `/var/log/messages` until reboot. If you have enabled persistent systemd journals (by creating the `/var/log/journal` directory), you might have a few more entries from before shutdown viewable with `journalctl`.

Before the shutdown job, there seems to be an Ansible job running `yum`:

```
Jul 15 03:01:53 xxxxxxxxxx python: ansible-ansible.legacy.yum Invoked with lock_timeout=30 \
    update_cache=False conf_file=None exclude=[] allow_downgrade=False disable_gpg_check=False \
    disable_excludes=None use_backend=auto state=latest disablerepo=[] skip_broken=False \
    releasever=None autoremove=False download_dir=None enable_plugin=[] installroot=/ \
    install_weak_deps=True name=['*'] download_only=False bugfix=False list=None \
    install_repoquery=True update_only=False disable_plugin=[] enablerepo=[] security=True \
    validate_certs=True
```

It might be a good idea to see if this `yum` operation brought in any kernel updates, and if it did, verify that the initramfs creation was successful. I think I've seen before cases where RHEL 7.x's initramfs creation fails because of e.g. filesystem being full because of `yum`'s package cache, and then the boot with the new kernel is going to fail, sometimes even before it can mount the root filesystem in read/write mode, which obviously means there will be no logs written from that boot attempt.

Since this is a VMware virtual machine, the logs of the virtualization hypervisor (and/or the vSphere management, if available) might tell more about what happened after the system went down; perhaps there was a scheduled hypervisor service break at that time, and the VMware admins were blocking the VMs from starting up until their part of the service break was done?

Also, I would not blindly trust the logged time values immediately after the reboot, until the system has started networking and enabled NTP time synchronization. In a mixed Windows/Linux VMware environment, it's possible to forget to disable VMware time synchronization. If the environment is dominated by Windows VMs, it's likely the VMware hosts are running their system clocks in local time... and the VMs virtual clocks would default to that time at start-up too.

If that's true, then you would see a time jump at boot when the NTP synchronization service starts up, probably roughly equal to the current UTC/DST offset at your site. If the after-boot timestamps later jump from Jul 15 08:3x:xx to roughly Jul 15 03:xx:xx, that would  suggest that your VM is configured to (incorrectly) assume its virtual hardware clock in UTC and you are running on a Windows-centric VMware environment somewhere within the UTC+4 (+DST, northern hemisphere) or UTC+5 (no DST) timezone.

Your ungraceful shutdown happened at some time between the system coming up at 15/07/2022 08:38:48.151:6 and the next boot at 18/07/2022 06:17:40.034:6. Your `/var/log/messages` excerpt does not cover that time interval.

To figure out what happened with that ungraceful shutdown, you'll need to find the **last log entries before time 18/07/2022 06:17:40**.

If there are **no logs in `/var/log/messages` after Jul 15 08:38:30**, then I would consider the possibility that the VM might have been hacked and (inexpertly) rootkitted. If that turns out to be true, any crash at shutdown might be a side effect of the rootkit and/or other malware in the VM, but that would probably be the least of your worries at that point...